# Wrong return-path with postfix, spamassassin on debian

Tags: debian, postfix-mta, spamassassin

i currently set up an new Server running the latest Debian.
Running postfix and spamassassin.

Spamassassin works as expected.

But with outgoing mail i have the problem that Spamassassin is modifing the "return-path".
Instead of the sender address it always uses it's own spamd mail account / user.
From is ok in the header. But not the return-path.

Corresponding line in master.cf from postfix is

```
spamassassin unix -     n       n       -       -       pipe
  user=debian-spamd argv=/usr/bin/spamc -f -e /usr/sbin/sendmail \ -oi -f${sender} ${recipient}
```

What is missing? 
Thanks for every help in advance.

Please remember: I'm using postfix. Together with it's sendmail.

Best Regards
Thomas

Edit:
Here are some lines i found in the log file. This may be the cause. But i have no idea what's the reason.

```
Sep 22 15:11:36  postfix/error[24169]: ABB891240069: to=<-oi@mail.myhost.de>, orig_to=<-oi>, relay=none, delay=0.02, delays=0/0/0/0.01, dsn=5.1.3, status=bounced (bad address syntax)
Sep 22 15:11:36  postfix/local[24168]: ABB891240069: to=<root@mail.myhost.de>, relay=local, delay=0.02, delays=0/0/0/0.01, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
Sep 22 15:11:36  postfix/error[24169]: ABB891240069: to=<-fthesender@myhost.de>, relay=none, delay=0.02, delays=0/0/0/0.02, dsn=5.1.3, status=bounced (bad address syntax)
```

Comment: Could you add log entries generated by postfix for single test message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your "sendmail by postfix" treats `-oi` and `-f${sender}` as recipients' addresses.

Fixe to try:
1) `\` before `-oi` is not needed in single line entry.

Comment: The backslash was the reason. Works like a charme now. Thank you very much